# Cannot format argument from within spdlog

Tags: c++, fmt, spdlog

I am trying to use `spdlog`. I incorporated it with my code, but now I am getting the following error:

```
....fmt\core.h(1016): error C2338: Cannot format argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types
  ....fmt/core.h(1013): note: while compiling class template member function 'int fmt::v6::internal::arg_mapper<Context>::map(...)'
          with
          [
              Context=context
          ]
  ....fmt/core.h(1213): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int fmt::v6::internal::arg_mapper<Context>::map(...)' being compiled
          with
          [
              Context=context
          ]
  ....fmt/core.h(1027): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v6::internal::arg_mapper<Context>' being compiled
          with
          [
              Context=context
          ]
  ....fmt/core.h(1198): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'fmt::v6::internal::mapped_type_constant<int,context>' being compiled
  ....fmt/core.h(1342): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned __int64 fmt::v6::internal::encode_types<Context,int,>(void)' being compiled
          with
          [
              Context=context
          ]
  ....fmt/format.h(3375): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v6::format_arg_store<context,int>' being compiled
  ....spdlog/details/fmt_helper.h(49): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v6::internal::buffer<char>> fmt::v6::format_to<char[6],int&,250,char>(fmt::v6::basic_memory_buffer<char,250,std::allocator<char>> &,const S (&),int &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              S=char [6]
          ]
```

... and this is the end of the error message. It never reaches my code, so I have no idea where to look at. Any ideas what could be the reason for this?

spdlog is version 1.6.1. The last error line is from here:

```
inline void pad2(int n, memory_buf_t &dest)
{
    if (n >= 0 && n < 100) // 0-99
    {
        dest.push_back(static_cast<char>('0' + n / 10));
        dest.push_back(static_cast<char>('0' + n % 10));
    }
    else // unlikely, but just in case, let fmt deal with it
    {
        fmt::format_to(dest, "{:02}", n);  // <--- HERE
    }
}
```

and it doesn't look particularly wrong to me.

---

Update: after some try-and-errors commenting out all `spdlog` invocations I narrowed it down to this:

`spdlog::info("Foo{}", Point{1, 2});`

Where `Point` is my own class in my own namespace. I do provide for it a way to print itself:

```
template<typename OStream>
OStream &operator<<(OStream &os, const Point &p) {
    return os << "[" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "]";
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `Point` class, please? Did you declare the `operator <<` in it?

Comment: Could you please provide some more code where you call the `spdlog::info`

Comment: Add `#include <spdlog/fmt/ostr.h>`

Comment: You need the special include @PiotrSkotnicki mentioned if you want your user defined type to be formatted using `operator<<`. Otherwise you need to provide a [fmt::formatter class specialization](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types).

Comment: @JorgeBellon I have a code, that prints user-defined class, but I didn't manually include that file and it works

Comment: The documentation [is pretty clear about that](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#std-ostream-support).

Comment: Yes, the documentation is clear, and yes that was my omission. Fixed now and works as intended. My only wish is that the error message was a little bit more helpful. @PiotrSkotnicki If you could promote your comment to an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*spdlog* uses the `{fmt}` library for formatting the output text, and that requires the `<fmt/ostream.h>` header file [to be included](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#std-ostream-support) in order to enable `std::ostream`-like support.

Regardless of using external implementation of the `{fmt}` library, or the one from spdlog sources itself, there's the special header `<spdlog/fmt/ostr.h>` that includes the file version that is in use.

Once included, spdlog should be able to use your `operator<<`.

Alternatively, you can create a custom formatter, that's also capable of parsing a formatting string:

```
template <>
struct fmt::formatter<Point> {
    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
        return ctx.end();
    }

    template <typename Context>
    auto format(const Point& p, Context& ctx) {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "[{}, {}]", p.x, p.y);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is overall correct: `spdlog` is based on `{fmt}` library, which has build-in `std::ostream` support including formatting of user-defined types that have an overloaded insertion operator (`operator<<`).

But starting from version 9 of `{fmt}` library, one needs to explicitly specialize `fmt::formatter` struct for user classes deriving it from `ostream_formatter` as follows:

```
#include <spdlog/fmt/ostr.h>

#if FMT_VERSION >= 90000
    template <> struct fmt::formatter<Point> : ostream_formatter{};
#endif
```

See: https://fmt.dev/dev/api.html#ostream-api